# ansible sudo option in playbook under all hosts fails

Tags: ansible

`sudo: yes` under `hosts: all` does't work! I've to specifically move it under hosts: www... any ideas why is this happening?

error message is:

```
failed: [centos7] => (item=[u'git']) => {"changed": true, "failed": true, "item": ["git"], "msg": "You need to be root to perform this command.\n", "rc": 1, "results": ["Loaded plugins: fastestmirror\n"]}

---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  #sudo: yes

- hosts: www
  sudo: yes
  remote_user: vagrant
  roles:
  - common
  #- oh-my-zsh
  #- nginx
```

Comment: What ansible versión is? Try with become:yes and become_user:root without become password.

Comment: Is common set sudo : yes per task but read become http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html

Comment: What are you trying to archive there? In above code you have two plays in one playbook. The first play has neither tasks nor roles. There might be a bug being triggered with this specific setup. But even if it would not cause that error, it wouldn't do anything at all.

Comment: @udondan my understanding is -host:all affects all host groups?

Comment: Yes, but still, there are no tasks and roles defined on that play. So there is nothing to do, no matter if sudo worked or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point in setting `sudo: yes` on a play which has no tasks to run, and if you set `gather_facts: no`, nothing will be run. So you should just remove that play from the playbook since it does nothing:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  sudo: yes
```

`sudo: yes` can be defined on a play level if you want all tasks in that play to run using `sudo`, but of course you can enable/disable sudo per task as well.

I would like to note that in the future you should use `become: yes` (by default uses `sudo`), since `sudo:` is deprecated and will be removed in future Ansible versions.